# How to store multiple database query logs in log file codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, backend, php-7

Want to save Query logs of all the database which has been used in Codeigniter application

Comment: Any updates guys ?

Comment: You've been waiting 21 minutes, patience mate. - What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you asking? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to store Query logs which were successfully done by the use of hooks in CodeIgniter but it works on default db. In my application model I have used more than two database which config is present in database.php but query logs store only for default DB please help on it.

Comment: turn on save queries for each of the db connection configuration arrays

Comment: not work torn on save queries for each db only default db logs save

Answer (score 0):

Use Codeignitor

$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

Comment: By using this log will not store in query log file it will store in the normal log file of Codeigniter I want to save this in query log file.

Comment: How to connect 2 database in Codeignitor

Comment: By Making multiple DB entries in database.php